# offline authentication using cookies, django

Tags: django, authentication, cookies, service-worker

I am building offline progressive web application for that I need Authentication in offline for existing user.

I am trying to store user authentication values like username and password in browser using cookies. but how to retrieve username and password form cookies and check authentication in offline using service worker. thanks in advance

Comment: I think this cannot be done. All the local code in your browser (including service workers) and all the local data (cookies, local storage) is editable by the user and therefore could be easily compromised. Why would you want to authenticate offline in the first place?

Comment: thanks petr. but is there any other ways to access like indexDB to store data and check for offline.

Comment: Sure you could store the credentials with some of the browser's APIs and later check against them, but this would not be secure at all. Everything that happens inside the browser is controllable by the browser and ultimately by the user, so they can forge the authenticity very easily. The thing that makes authentication on the internet secure is that the credentials and the authentication process are stored and run on the server with no way of user manipulating that environment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Service Workers are not for authentication check. You can use cookies or localStorage to store authentication details if you compromised with safety measure.

If the cookie is available in your browser to navigate the user to the next page, do that. Use service worker to serve cached files.